# The height of a tower is measured at the angle of two different points in the same direction on the ground.

Tags: calculus, geometry

The height of a tower is measured at the angle of two different points in the same direction on the ground. The angle of $M$ point to the tower is $\beta=50^\circ$ and the angle of $N$ point to the tower is $\delta=35^\circ$. These angles were measured with a change of $1^\circ$ at most. $MN$ interval was measured as $x=100\ m$ with a maximum of $0.1\text{%}$ error. What is the calculated height of the building? What is the error at the calculated height? According to which measurement is the calculated height more sensitive? Why?

I've to calculate this problem. But I've no idea about it.

Comment: What have you tried? Perhaps start by labeling unknowns and writing the relationships between them.

Comment: You must show you own efforts .

Comment: Draw a sketch. Use trigonometry. Find relations from shared edges.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: The image of what's going on (not to scale):
$AB=99.9,\, AC=100.1$,
$\angle DAH=36^\circ,\,\angle EAH=34^\circ$,
$\angle DBH=51^\circ,\,\angle GCH=49^\circ$,
$HT$ is the tower height, $\angle THA=90^\circ$.
[image]
$HA$ and $HB$ or $HC$ can be found from a right triangle in terms of $x=HT$ (if $T$ is $E$ or $G$) using basic trigonometry. Then you have a linear equation over $x$ -- one for minimum height, another for maximum height.
Answer will be $\frac{\min+\max}{2}$ and the absolute error $\frac{\max-\min}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's make sense